# Unique Constraints for specified key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unique

In Mongoose, we can apply unique constraints for one key by internal validator.

While how to achieve the same effect by native NodeJS Driver?

Create one index for the key with unique option in collection? While it will be harmful to the performance of write (index will be updated for each insertion).

Are there any other ways to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting Question: Probably this helps: https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique

Comment: @Matthias, thanks, yes, this maybe the only way I find now to do a unique insertion. Just as I mention above, which will impact the write performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniqueness can be maintained by creating indexes and telling MongoDB to make the key(s) unique.

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Hope this is what you were looking for